# Script to open new git bash and run command in window

Tags: bash, window, command-prompt

I'm writing an script (`.bat` or `.sh`) which will open some new git-bash terminal and do some commands in window OS
I'm expecting my file working like below flow

```
#my script

open new git bash terminal -> do some commands to execute in git bash
wait user press any key to continue

open another bash terminal -> do some other commands
wait user press any key to continue
```

I've already have script run with Command-Prompt, but I want to do it on git-bash command. This is my script:

```
start cmd.exe /k %KAFKA_PATH%\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat %KAFKA_PATH%\config\zookeeper.properties

echo "Wait until zookeeper started."
pause
```

Comment: I have the same problem.
I need a git-bash script that will open several new git-bash windows and in each will run a different command.

I have no issue to open new git-bash windows with:
start "" "full path to git-bash.lnk"
but how can I run the command in the new window?